# Mlodinow. The Drunkard's Walk. An example from the book.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This excerpt is from Leonard Mlodinow's book The Drunkard's Walk:

> And
>   although Fortune is fair in potentialities, she is not fair in outcomes.
>   That means that if each of 10 Hollywood executives tosses 10 coins,
>   although each has an equal chance of being the winner or the loser,
>   in the end there will be winners and losers. In this example, the
>   chances are 2 out of 3 that at least 1 of the executives will score 8 or
>   more heads or tails.

How can it be proved with math?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us look at the probability of one executive getting $8$ or more heads/tails when tossing a coin $10$ times. $$ P(\text{# of heads}\geq 8 \text{ or # of tails} \geq 8) = 2 \times \dfrac1{2^{10}} \left(\dbinom{10}8 + \dbinom{10}9 +\dbinom{10}{10} \right) = \dfrac7{64}$$
Hence, the probability that one executives will score $7$ or less heads/tails$ = 1 - \dfrac7{64} = \dfrac{57}{64}$.

Hence, the probability that at-least one of the executives will score $8$ or more heads/tails is nothing but $\left(1 - \text{ the probability that all the executives will score $7$ or less heads or tails} \right)$.

The probability that all executives will score $7$ or less heads or tails is $ \left(\dfrac{57}{64} \right)^{10}$. Hence, the desired probability is $$1 - \left(\dfrac{57}{64} \right)^{10} = 0.685986140417819036628477302741657695150934159755706787109375 \approx \dfrac23$$

Answer (score 1):

Call an executive *balanced* if she got between $3$ and $7$ heads and call $b$ the chances that an executive is balanced. One asks for the chances $p$ that at least one executive is not balanced, that is, $p=1-q$ where $q$  are the chances that every executive is balanced, hence $q=b^{10}$.

There are $1+10+45+45+10+1=112$ ways to be unbalanced on a total of $2^{10}=1024$ ways hence $b=1-112/1024=57/64$ and $p=1-(57/64)^{10}=0.6860$.

Answer (score 0):

First find the probability $p$ that any person tossing 10 coins will score between $3$ and $7$  heads (the number of heads follows a Binomial distribution).

Since they toss the coins independently, the probability that *all* of them score between $3$ and $7$ is $p^{10}$.

The event that at least one scores $8$ or more heads, or $2$ or fewer heads (so $8$ or more tails) happens then with probability $1 - p^{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that each coin toss is independent, and that the coin is fair.

Tossing 10 coins, the total number of heads $X$ follows a binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}\left(10,\frac{1}{2}\right)$. The probability that one executive scores 8 or more heads or tails equals:
$$
    \mathbb{P}( X \leqslant 2 \lor X \geqslant 8) = 1 - \mathbb{P}( 3 \leqslant X \leqslant 7) = 1 - \sum_{k=3}^7 \frac{1}{2^{10}} \binom{10}{k} = \frac{7}{64} = 1- p
$$
The probability that none of the executives obtains score 8 or more of head or tails equals:
$$
      1 - p^{10} = 1 - \left(\frac{57}{64}\right)^{10} \approx 0.685986
$$

Comment: could you explain why are **X** <= **2** also included into required probability?

Comment: Since $X$ is the number of heads, $X \geqslant 8$ means 8 or more heads. 8 or more tails translates into 2 or less heads, thus $X \leqslant 2$.